# Time-traveler pretending seminal '60s music is his own work

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

In his [latest "Books to Look for" column in F&SF](http://www.sfsite.com/fsf/2012/cdl1205.htm), Charles de Lint asks the following:

> Oh, and while I have your ear. This combination of time travel and the Village in the '60s reminds me of a story that I've been trying to track down for years—for so long, in fact, that I'm beginning to think I must have imagined it. Naturally, I can't remember the author or title. But it was about **a fellow who went back to that time with a crate full of seminal music recordings from the same era (Dylan, etc.) and then proceeded to pawn them off as his own.**
>
> If that rings a bell, could you drop me a line and let me know what the story is?

Anybody here able to help him out?

Comment: Marty McFly? :)

Comment: @DVK He did try something like that.  I think it was a Sports Almanac though.

Comment: @Kalamane McFly also invented Chuck Barry's guitar licks, via his cousin Marvin.

Comment: I think it could be argued that Chuck Barry still invented those, as that's where Marty learned them.

Comment: Well it's the classical Shakespeare's paradox : Marty learned them from Chuck Berry, and Chuck Berry used them because of Marty... So who invented them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gordon Van Gelder (the editor of F&SF) has [made known](http://www.sfsite.com/fsf/blog/forum/topic.php?id=1864#post-13258) that de Lint got several reader responses, identifying the story as [*Bob Dylan, Troy Jonson, and the Speed Queen*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70852), by F. Paul Wilson.